Applying a Wirtinger-like inequality to get a bound for a differential equation.
Here I am considering the following problem.
I have some $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ smooth with the property that $f''≥-Cf$ for some $C > 0$.
We have that $f(0)=0$  but $f'(0)>0$.
Can I find an $R>0$ just determined by $C$ such that $f>0$ on $(0,R)$?
I have the following hint:
'The following variant of Wirtinger's inequality may be useful and can be assumed without proof: if $g$ is a $C^1$ function on $[0, L]$ vanishing at $0$ , then $\int_0^L|g(x)|^2 d x \leqslant \frac{L}{2 \pi} \int_0^L\left|g^{\prime}(x)\right|^2 d x$.'
It is not clear to me how to apply it: all of the bounds I get end up being self-referential and not that helpful here.

I don't see how to use Wirtinger's inequality, but I think the following method could work: Since $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)>0$ the function is positive on a small interval $(0,\delta)$. Let $f$ have a first positive zero $x_0$, that is
$f(x_0)=0$ and $f(x) > 0$ $(x \in (0,x_0))$ (otherwise $f(x)>0$ $(x>0)$). Note that $f'(x_0) \le 0$. We show $x_0  \ge \pi/\sqrt{C}$. Assume by contradiction $x_0  < \pi/\sqrt{C}$.
Choose $\gamma > C$ such that still $x_0  < \pi/\sqrt{\gamma}$. We have
$$
0 < \int_0^{x_0} \sin(\sqrt{\gamma} x) f(x) dx =  [-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}}\cos(\sqrt{\gamma} x)f(x)]_0^{x_0} + \int_0^{x_0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}}\cos(\sqrt{\gamma} x) f'(x) dx
$$
$$
=\int_0^{x_0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}}\cos(\sqrt{\gamma} x) f'(x) dx = [\frac{1}{\gamma}\sin(\sqrt{\gamma} x)f'(x)]_0^{x_0} - \int_0^{x_0} \frac{1}{\gamma}\sin(\sqrt{\gamma} x) f''(x) dx 
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\gamma}\sin(\sqrt{\gamma} x_0)f'(x_0) - \int_0^{x_0} \frac{1}{\gamma}\sin(\sqrt{\gamma} x) f''(x) dx 
$$
$$
\le \frac{1}{\gamma}\sin(\sqrt{\gamma} x_0)f'(x_0) + \int_0^{x_0} \frac{C}{\gamma}\sin(\sqrt{\gamma} x) f(x) dx.
$$
Since $C/\gamma < 1$ we get
$$
0 < (1-\frac{C}{\gamma})\int_0^{x_0} \sin(\sqrt{\gamma} x) f(x) dx \le  \frac{1}{\gamma}\sin(\sqrt{\gamma} x_0)f'(x_0), 
$$
Hence $f'(x_0)>0$, a contradiction.
Thus $R=\pi/\sqrt{C}$ seems to work.

This is roughly what i had in mind, thank you. Indeed, the question stated that the Wirtinger inequality may be helpful but did not force us to use it so it seems like there are probably a range of approaches other than whatever one they happened to have had in mind.
